# Cache control by htaccess with condition

Tags: regex, .htaccess, caching, browser-cache

I have cache control set by htaccess for all images by this

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A600
ExpiresByType image/gif A604800
ExpiresByType image/png A604800
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A604800
</IfModule>
```

It works great, but I have also pictures from web camera, which change every 20 minutes. So I need to cache all images except these from camera.

I can write regular expression for those from web camera, they have name which others pictures never can have. But how to put there some condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable cache for certain matching files :

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
   ExpiresActive On
   ExpiresDefault A600
   ExpiresByType image/gif A604800
   ExpiresByType image/png A604800
   ExpiresByType image/jpeg A604800
</IfModule>

# disable caching for IMG_20130420_535615.jpg type of files
<FilesMatch "IMG_[0-9]+_[0-9]+\.jpg$">
   FileETag None
   <ifModule mod_headers.c>
     Header unset ETag
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
     Header set Pragma "no-cache"
     Header set Expires "Tue, 14 Jan 1975 01:00:00 GMT"
   </ifModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Thank you, just one thing. Can I put <FilesMatch..> inside <ifModules mod_expires.c> and set expires like others images with `ExpiresByDate` just for smaller time interval? Because I can cache these images for few minutes. It isn't necessary to see new image immediately after new is captured.

Comment: Yes sure you can put `<FilesMatch..> inside <ifModules mod_expires.c>`

Comment: So before `</IfModule>` I put this `<FilesMatch "myregex"> ExpiresByType image/jpeg A600 </FilesMatch>` for cache these pictures for 10 minutes. This override expires date set before, am I right?

Comment: yes that's correct, you can put that line just above `<FilesMatch...>` line also

Comment: These instructions are sequential so whatever comes later overrides value before it.